# Simple HTML Library to display statistics charts inside the web-page

Tags: library, charts, statistics, dashboard, web

I am a backend programmer. I have a back-end program that has some statistical data. Something like conversion rate change in time for e-commerce categories. I need to show these statistics to customers. I don't know js/css/asp.net to create beautiful web-site with charts. Just know the HTML basics. What is the best way to automatically create some site with charts? I remember that MS SQL server has something similar but I didn't use this functionality. Do you know how to do my task easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a purely programmatic solution, [Essential Chart for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/chart/line) is a JS based library to consider.

[Syncfusion Dashboards](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) are an option if you want to develop the charts using the designer (drag and drop designer). The created chart based dashboards can then be embedded in your webpage.

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.